# How can I import a CSV to RDF using Apache Jena?

Tags: csv, import, jena, data-conversion

Is it possible to convert from command line csv to rdf using Apache Jena?

Is it possible to supply meta data, helping in conversion?

Example of dumb try with `riot`:

```
./apache-jena-3.3.0/bin/riot --base='http://example.com/csvtest/' --syntax=csv --output=ttl csv_dbs_examples/csv_inputs/CDs.csv 
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.jena.ext.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:770)
        at org.apache.jena.ext.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4153)
        at org.apache.jena.ext.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:5060)
        at org.apache.jena.atlas.lib.cache.CacheGuava.getOrFill(CacheGuava.java:58)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver$IRIResolverNormal.resolveSilentCache(IRIResolver.java:470)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver$IRIResolverNormal.resolveSilent(IRIResolver.java:454)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.resolve(IRIResolver.java:328)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver$IRIResolverSync.resolve(IRIResolver.java:489)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.resolveIRI(IRIResolver.java:254)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.system.IRIResolver.resolveString(IRIResolver.java:233)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.ReaderRIOTCSV.parse(ReaderRIOTCSV.java:89)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.ReaderRIOTCSV.read(ReaderRIOTCSV.java:67)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.read(RDFParser.java:293)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parseNotUri(RDFParser.java:283)
        at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:233)
        at riotcmd.CmdLangParse.parseRIOT(CmdLangParse.java:286)
        at riotcmd.CmdLangParse.parseFile(CmdLangParse.java:216)
        at riotcmd.CmdLangParse.exec$(CmdLangParse.java:161)
        at riotcmd.CmdLangParse.exec(CmdLangParse.java:127)
        at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
        at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
        at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
        at riotcmd.riot.main(riot.java:34)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is http://jena.apache.org/documentation/csv/ (which is being called in the question) but this is not CSVW (the W3C standard). There are several CSVW conversion tools - you can convert to RDF then read the RDF into Jena.

The actual stacktrace is a bug in 3.3.0 (Apache Jena 3.2.0 should work).

> Update from @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: Confirmed that it looks like bug in
>   Jena 3.3.0, as it works with Jena 3.1.1

Comment: > ... is bug in 3.3.0

do you have a tracking bug ?

> Apache Jena 3.2.0 should work
Where is officially hosted 3.2.0 ?
"http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-3.2.0.tar.gz" -> "Not Found
The requested URL /dist/jena/binaries/apache-jena-3.2.0.tar.gz was not found on this server."

Anyhow, I confirm , with Jedna 3.1.1 which I have copy it works!